# Are Rust Match Expressions Type Indeterminate?

Tags: rust

Reading a Rust tutorial I found the following code snippet:

```
let f = File::open("hello.txt");

let mut f = match f {
    Ok(file) => file,
    Err(e) => return Err(e)
};
```

This seems that `f` could have the value of type `Result<_, _>` (if `f == Err(e)`) or a value of type `_` (i.e., whatever type `file` happens to be).

So does this mean that match expressions in Rust are type indeterminate?

Comment: I think `return Err(e)` is not setting the value of `f`, it's breaking out of the `match` and returning a value from the function.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: If `f` has type `std::fs::File`, then `f` might have type `std::fs::File` hence not `Result<_, _>`. Type indeterminate means that `f` could have one of two unequal types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, types aren't indeterminate. You are first creating a binding of type `Result<io::File, io::Error>`. Then, you are creating a new (mutable) binding for `f` of type `io::File` (because that's what is contained in the `Ok` variant of the `Result` enum in your case) This new binding shadows the old one, just like a a block in, say, Perl (and C/C++ etc.) would introduce a new scope:

```perl
my $x = [42, 24];
{
    # new scope
    my $x = $x->[0];
    say Dumper $x; # 42, an INT
}
say Dumper $x; # [42, 24], an ARRAY
```

In Rust, `let` can be thought of as introducing a new scope similarly, shadowing the previous binding.

Since you also `return` *out of your function* when you encounter an `Err(_)`, the compiler is still able to infer the type of the second binding `f` to be `io::File`.